# Ignoring drillthrough filter on a sheet

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem with a measure I'm currently working on.

I have 2 sheets, I drillthrough from sheet1 to sheet2 on column_A, but I also have synced slicers on both sheets for column_A that I use.

My measure needs to get all the selected values from column_A from sheet1, but when I'm on sheet2 I can only get the available values for the subgroup of column_A that I drilled through on or all the values using ALL()

Is there a way to get the original selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but you could filter the first page by a duplicate table, here Table2

[image]

and the main page

[image]

and the drilldown page with the measure

```
Measure = calculate( max('Table'[column_A]), REMOVEFILTERS('Table'), KEEPFILTERS(Table2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Had to ask a colleague of mine and he came up with a solution just like this. Had to multiply the dimension table. It works, I don't know how I didn't think about it.